# First try setting up Apache Reverse Proxy - css and images not being found

Tags: html, css, apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to put a working web site server behind a reverse proxy - both using Apache.

Server1 (10.27.27.60) (in a VM) has six different web sites configured using VirtualHost files structured like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain1.org
    ServerAlias mydomain1.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain1.org/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain1.org/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/mydomain1.org/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set up a new VM Apache server r-proxy1 (10.27.27.66) and set it up to proxy just a single domain.  My router forwards port 80 to r-proxy1.

I must have looked at 10+ sites on how to do it and there was minimal consistency - so it was impossible to know for sure what was essential or not.  Eventually I came up with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias example.*
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/AccessLog.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/ErrorLog.log
    TransferLog /var/www/logs/TransferLog.log
    
    ProxyPass / http://10.27.27.60
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.27.27.60
</VirtualHost>
```

The site now appears but the css, images and js files are not being found.  The folders for these files are in subfolders in the html folder and are all referenced in the html like './css/style.css'.

Chrome is showing errors like: GET http://example.org/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Proxy Error)

I have tried moving the css etc. files to the root html folder and changing the html reference and the files are still not found (GET http://example.org/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Proxy Error))

I have tried adding a / at the end of the ProxyPass lines and have tried adding additional lines like

```
ProxyPass /css/ http://10.27.27.60/css/
ProxyPassReverse /css http://10.27.27.60/css/
```

into the VirtualHost file but the errors remain.  My problem seems to be common but none of the suggestions I have found have helped.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried adding
 <Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
but makes no difference.

Comment: I have just noticed that the reference in my html: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">  also generates the same sort of error: GET http://dessergroup.org/favicon.ico 502 (Proxy Error) even though the file is there in the html folder.